# How to use system call in php 5.4 (safe_mode=off)

Tags: php, system-calls

I have read safe_mode directive was removed from php.ini.
And then how can I use system call(exec, system, passthru, etc.) in php 5.4?

I need some guide, however, I could not find anything.

Comment: did you not see the manual pages in php.net

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: if safe_mode is off (or completely removed) you can always invoke these functions, just the way as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to everyone,

I found my terrible mistake done.
I mistook javascript-working-area as php-working-area.

It works well on the php 5.4 as php

Answer (score 0):

For all information please check the PHP.net site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

the functions `exec()`, `system()`, etc are still there and function the same way as PHP 5.3 with safe_mode = off.  The one thing you need to be concerned with is escaping user data like this:

```
<?php
   exec('mv ' . escapeshellcmd($_GET['originial_file']) . ' ' . escapeshellcmd($_GET['new_file']));
```

Comment: Thank you :)
But when I use some command without any parameter like below,

1.
exec("dir", $output);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
2.
$last_line = system('dir', $retval);
echo "<pre>$last_line</pre>";
3.
passthru("dir",$err);
echo "<pre>$err</pre>";
4.
$output = `dir`;
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
5.
$output = shell_exec('dir');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
</pre>
anyone above does not work.. In this case, there is only command without parameter.
Could you tell me something that I missed for using this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested these code below on other env.
When I test same codes on php 5.3 & linux, they work good.
But, the same code run on php 5.4 & XAMPP(Windows APM), they do not work.
Therefore, I make a decision carefully that this is the issue coming from environment not code. Could you tell me some guide for me?
(Now... XAMPP(httpd) runs with the right of some user in Administrator's group.)

exec("netstat -antu", $output); echo "$output";

$last_line = system('ls', $retval); echo "$last_line";

passthru("ls",$err); echo "$err";

$output = `ls`; echo "$output";

$output = shell_exec('ls'); echo "$output";

Comment: And one more information...
When I try php 5.4 built-in webserver on Windows machine according to http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php, it works good as is done on php5.3 & linux.